# Exactly wait for a timer overflow on the MSP430

Tags: timer, msp430

Is there an easy way to exactly wait for a timer overflow on the MSP430?

The timer overflow interrupt is a little late and not exact, depending on the timing of the currently executed instruction. A waiting loop doesn't snap on a single system cycle either.

So I guess one would schedule a compare interrupt just before the timer overflows and then do some CPU based wait until the timer hits 0. What instructions to use for? Is this possible with C code only?

Comment: I run the MSP430 at 8Mhz. I need cycle stable latency for high resolution PWM operations. 
@dwelch well, C does no magic and translate to machine instructions anyway. So we have less control while writing the code, but if freasable instructions are issued, the result will work the same way as assembly written code would. If in doubt, one can check the assembly issued by the compiler. Question is if there is a single cycle instruction that jumps on itself for waiting, and if can be issued in C. Or if there are other instructions, that we can select depending on the cycles left to eat them.

Comment: Unless you want a plethora of other features, then usually one or two fall back to some software implementation. And MSP430's sport a lot of cool peripherials, but almost none of them sports all features at once. Even less do if one starts prototyping by LaunchPad boards.

Comment: I guess if we talk about latencies and inaccuracies of about 10 cycles or more, 16 vs 8 Mhz doesn't change the game. 160 MHz would then, but that is far out of reach.

I limit myself to the MSP430 because I've already implemented 9 of 10 features of my current project on it. There are several controllers out there yes, and several application notes how to run LCDs, run from battery for years, handle SD cards and touch sensors or provide a realtime clock. However, stitching this all together requires quite some effort and now I just need accurate PWM in addidition to all that already running.

Comment: For example even poor audio (eg. 32000kHz 8 bit PCM) requires over 8MHz timing resolution if played via PWM.

Comment: Why aren't you using the timer output directly? Or DMA?

Comment: The MCU used sports no dma, and the timer can only drive one certain pin per compare unit, in only one direction. If for example two pins need to be driven inverted, an precise action on the timer overflow is needed. Also if PWM value has to be updated with every cycle, it must happen precisely to allow for the full amplitude range. Some devices do not feature latches for the compare value registers, that would solve this problem accurately without waiting.